# EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3000 in Windows Next js

Tags: windows, next.js

When I try to start the next js server with `yarn dev` it will throw me up with this error. I need to restart the entire system in order for it to work.
And I'm running it on windows. It takes forever.

```sh
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1301:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1503:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3000
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "solution" on windows for many people seems to disable virtual ethernet adapters (especially when you use docker). It could also be that another program is using the same port, which you can find out by using `netstat -a`.

I disable all vEthernet adapters that were not in use and restarted. At some point it magically worked again.
The setting can be found here: Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections

source:
https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1705#issuecomment-508846475

(Honestly the most annoying bug I had in a long time and a reason to switch to linux)

Answer (score 25):

run this .bat file

```
%1 mshta vbscript:CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute("cmd.exe","/c %~s0 ::","","runas",1)(window.close)&&exit
cd /d "%~dp0"
net stop winnat
net start winnat
exit
```

Comment: This worked for me but would be nicer with even the briefest of explanations.

Comment: explanation: this basically restarts the Windows NAT service, which may help with some networking issues for containers or VMs. It's most likely that you are using docker or something like this.

Comment: Explanation: It uses mshta to execute a VBScript command, which opens a Command Prompt (cmd.exe) with elevated privileges (run as administrator). Inside the Command Prompt, it changes the current directory (cd) to the directory of the batch script ("%~dp0"). It stops the "winnat" service using the net stop command. It starts the "winnat" service using the net start command. Finally, it exits the Command Prompt. In summary, this script is designed to stop and then start the "winnat" service on a Windows system with administrator privileges

Comment: Running "net stop winnat" and then "net start winnat" would be enough

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if this is the same issue but my error was:

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3000
... Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1357:8)
    at processTicksAnd
```

And [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/Error%3A+listen+EACCES%3A+permission+denied+3000%3B) fixed it: `Restarting the service "Host Network Service"`

Comment: You a Top G for this one!.. Strange error. Came out of nowhere...

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks.

Comment: Open CMD (Command prompt with admin privilege)
Then run:
NET STOP "Host Network Service"
To stop the service
Then run,
NET START "Host Network Service" 
to restart it.

I saw the command here: 
https://superuser.com/questions/301765/restart-a-windows-service-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was happening because the port used belong to reserved ports for Hyper-V.

This port range changes when I restart my computer, so sometimes I used to get the error and sometimes I don't.

It happened as I was building multiple Nextjs apps, and suddenly I'm unable to start one. I tried elevating the CMD to admin but access denied error, even tried finding the process associated with port but there was none.

I tried multiple ports like 3001, 3002, 3006, 3009 etc but nothing worked.

Here's the error: Error while starting Nextjs app, EACCES null:3001

[image: Error while starting Nextjs app, EACCES null:3001]

In order to check reserved ports by Windows you can use cmd/powershell with:

`netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

[image: checking reserved ports in windows]

The issue is described in: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5514

**General workround** (in comment 554587817): https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-554587817

**Fast workround:** choose a port that not belong to reserved ranges

`npm run dev -- -p 4000`

OR

Add the port specifier in the scripts section of package json file by editing dev, like this:

`"dev": "next dev -p 4000"`

and now it works:

[image: starting nextjs app with custom port]

This is also mentioned in the [post here](https://superuser.com/questions/1437780/how-to-fix-listen-eacces-permission-denied-on-any-port).

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) running on that port. Just open http://localhost:3000 and maybe you find out what's running there and stop it at *Services* (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

`EACESS` is only thrown when you don't have access to the port you want to use, unlike Linux, windows probably has more PORTs that require administrative privileges, 3000 might just be one of them, even if it's not being used, so increase your port number a little bit, add one more zero.

as mentioned by another user - that up to `3016` are being used for administrative purposes, so you can use them, the first address near `3000` you can use is `3017`

```
C:\Users\thisisMe> netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

Protocol tcp Port Exclusion Ranges

Start Port    End Port
----------    --------
      2917        3016
      3047        3146
      5357        5357
     14645       14744
     48752       48851
     49052       49151
     49252       49351
     50000       50059     *

* - Administered port exclusions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `.next` folder, close and open your code editor or terminal, and rerun your dev server `npm run dev`. That works for me